# Getting information about music that is popular in a country

Tags: python, beginner, xml

I have this code below that has 6 distinct parts:

- Necessary imports
- Get  the top artists from a specific country using last fm api
- Get some info about this returned artists
- Get top albums from that returned artists
- Get some info about these returned albums
- Get tracks of each returned album

**Issue:**

The code is presented below with a title for each part. The code despite is working it is in a sequential way. But I would like to have each specific part in a separate function.

The issue is that there are variables in one part that are necessary for other part. For exemple in the code of the part "Get Top Albums from the returned artists" its necessary to store the title of the album with                 `albums[ID]['title'] = name`. But if this part code "Get Top Albums from the returned artists" is in a function for example `getTopAlbumsFromReturnedArtists()` it's not working, it appears:

```
"Unresolved reference ID".
```

Do you know how to properly divide this sequential code below into separate functions?

**Imports**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import musicbrainzngs
import json
import urllib.request
import socket


api_key = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"
musicbrainzngs.set_useragent("app", "version", contact=None)
```

**Get top artists from a specific country**

```
artists = {}

for i in range(1,3):
    artistslist = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&page='+str(i)+'&api_key='+api_key)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artistslist.content)
    for node in tree:
        for artist in node.findall('artist'):
            name = artist.find('name').text
            url = artist.find('url').text
            mbid = artist.find('mbid').text
            artists[ID] = {}
            artists[ID]['id'] = ID
            artists[ID]['name'] = name
            artists[ID]['mbid'] = mbid
            ID+=1
```

**Get some info about returned artists**

```
for i,v in artists.items():
    if artists[i]['mbid'] != "None":
        info = musicbrainzngs.get_artist_by_id(artists[i]['mbid'])
        information = dict(list(info.values())[0])

        if 'area' in information:
            artists[i]['location'] = information['area']['name']
        else:
            artists[i]['location'] = "None"
    else:
        artists[i]['location'] = "None"

    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    artist = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='+chosen+'&api_key='+api_key)

    url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist={}&api_key={}'.format(v['name'], api_key)
    artist = requests.get(url)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artist.content)
    if tree.find('artist') is None:
        continue
    for node in tree.find('artist').getchildren():
        for tag in node.findall('tag'):
            if v.get('Tags'):
                v['Tags'].append(tag.find('name').text)
            else:
                v['Tags'] = [tag.find('name').text]
```

**Get Top Albums from that returned artists**

```
albums = {}

for i,v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    topalbuns = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist='+chosen+'&api_key='+api_key+'&limit=5')
    tree = ET.fromstring(topalbuns.content)
    for node in tree:
        for album in node:
            name = album.find('name').text
            url = album.find('url').text
            playcount = album.find('playcount').text
            albums[ID] = {}
            albums[ID]['ID'] = ID
            albums[ID]['artist'] = artists[i]['name']
            albums[ID]['artistID'] = artists[i]['id']
            albums[ID]['title'] = name
            albums[ID]['mbid'] = mbid

            ID+=1
```

**Get Albums information**

```
for i,v in albums.items():
    albums[i]['Image'] = "None"
    albums[i]['description'] = "None"
    if albums[i]['mbid'] != "None":
        try:
            info = musicbrainzngs.get_release_by_id(albums[i][3])
            information = dict(list(info.values())[0])
            print(information)
            if 'date' in information:
                dates = information['date']
                albums[i]['date'] = dates
            else:
                albums[i]['date'] = "None"
        except:
            albums[i]['date'] = "None"
    else:
        albums[i]['date'] = "None"
    artist = albums[i]['artist'].replace(" ","+")
    title = albums[i]['title'].replace(" ", "+")
    album = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key='+api_key+'&artist='+artist+'&album='+title)

    tree = ET.fromstring(album.content)
    for node in tree:
        for artist in node:
            if (artist.get('size') == "large"):
                if (artist.text is not None):
                    albums[i]['image'] = artist.text
            for wiki in artist.findall('summary'):
                if (wiki.text is not None):
                    albums[i]['description'] = wiki.text
                else:
                    albums[i]['description'] = "None"
```

**Get Tracks from albums**

```
tracks = {}
for i,v in albums.items():
    artist = albums[i]['artist'].replace(" ","+")
    title = albums[i]['title'].replace(" ", "+")
    album = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key='+api_key+'&artist='+artist+'&album='+title)
    tree = ET.fromstring(album.content)
    for node in tree:
        for artist in node.findall('tracks'):
            for track in artist.findall('track'):
                rank = track.get('rank')
                name = track.find('name').text
                length = track.find('duration').text
                url = track.find('url').text
                tracks[ID] = {}
                tracks[ID]['title'] = name
                tracks[ID]['number'] = rank
                tracks[ID]['artist'] = albums[i]['artist']
                tracks[ID]['album'] = albums[i]['title']
                tracks[ID]['albumID'] = albums[i]['ID']
                tracks[ID]['length'] = length
                ID+=1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Imports**

First, let me suggest you look at the [PEP 8 style guide.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) I don't follow all of the suggestions myself, but some of them make good sense, including the suggestions on the arrangement and ordering of imports:

1. Internal then third-party then local.
2. Simple imports, then named imports.
3. Avoid wildcard imports.

Which gives us:

```
import json
import requests
import socket
import urllib.request

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import musicbrainzngs
```

While we're on the subject, I notice that your web requests are going to a site called **audioscrobbler.** I'll suggest that if they don't provide an API module in Python, you should go ahead and write one that fits your needs:

```
import audioscrobbler
```

(**NOTE:** A little searching provides this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/audioscrobblerws/0.1.1 - I don't know if it's right for your needs.)

I'll further recommend that your audioscrobbler module should accept the API key as an external setting. Which means you need one more local module:

```
import private_data
```

It's a good idea to separate your private data from your source code, especially since you might be tempted to put your source up on a code-sharing site like bitbucket or github. This way you won't "forget" to scrub out the secrets when you post an update at 3am one night...

You can set your api key during your initial startup:

```
audioscrobbler.set_api_key(private_data.audioscrobbler_api_key)
musicbrainzngs.set_useragent("app", "version", contact=None)
```

Your `audioscrobbler` module can define very simple functions, extracting just the `get()` lines from your current code. This code:

```
album = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key='+api_key+'&artist='+artist+'&album='+title)
```

becomes this code:

```
album = audioscrobbler.get_album_info(album=title, artist=artist)
```

Right now it's just a wrapper. That's probably all it needs to be. But if you parse the result, you might be able to move the import of the HTTP and XML libraries into the audioscrobbler module entirely, which simplifies the rest of your program.

**Get top artists from a specific country**

I would suggest that this becomes another call to your `audioscrobbler` package:

```
artists = audioscrobbler.get_top_artists_by_country(country='spain', limit=30, fields='name mbid')
```

You can make the web API calls smart about what fields they return, and let them handle knowing how to implement a limit of three pages (is that 10 per, or 5 per or ...?).

**Get some info about returned artists**

Now here you add in a new service - musicbrainzngs. So it's not all calls to the audioscrobbler! But there's a mistake I think you're making (I could be wrong - check this): you're using dictionaries when you should just use lists.

```
for i,v in artists.items():
    if artists[i]['mbid'] != "None":
```

If we look at this code, what's in the `i` value? It's the key from the `artists` dictionary. But the artists dictionary was built like this:

```
artists[ID] = {}
...
ID+=1
```

You built it, using a totally artificial ID that you made up. You might just as well say `artists[ID] = {}; ID += 1` and use a list. Except that function is built-in: `artists.append(...stuff...)`

If you do that, you can iterate over the artists just using:

```
for artist in artists:
```

The second part of this code looks like it should be another function in your `audioscrobbler` module.

**Get Top Albums from that returned artists**

In this section, you are making the same error you made in the artists section. You don't need a dictionary keyed by an arbitrary ID. Just create and append to a list.

**Get Tracks from albums**

Likewise here. There's a some added code for your audioscrobbler module, and a list where you're using a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the things we can do to improve performance:

- install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and replace `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` with:

  ```
  from lxml import etree as ET
  ```

  this should seriously improve the XML parsing speed
- you can also save on the network as well by re-using a [`requests.Session()` instance](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

You can also use `enumerate()` instead of handling `ID` manually. And, I am not sure you need that `for node in tree` loop at all.

The first part of the code hence can look something like:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

artists = {}

url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&page={page}&api_key={api_key}'
with requests.Session() as session:
    for page in range(1, 3):
        response = session.get(url.format(page=page, api_key=api_key)
        tree = ET.fromstring(response.content)
        for index, artist in enumerate(tree.findall('artist')):
            artists[index] = {
                'id': index,
                'name': artist.findtext('name'),
                'mbid': artist.findtext('mbid')
            }
```

Note the use of `findtext()` shortcut.

I am also not absolutely sure about the `artists` data structure - why not using a list instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to go about it using different models of abstraction, using functions ([documentation](https://www.codementor.io/kaushikpal/user-defined-functions-in-python-8s7wyc8k2)) for example:

```
def functionname(parameters):
    stuff_to_happen
```

You should pass in data to the functions as parameters. You need to give the functions the data structure holding the track info so that they can do what they need.

You could also use objected oriented programming. Try to make a class called `TrackManager`. A class can have functions and data that the class attributes can access.

Then you just call the functions in appropriate order.